# Detecting line from noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction, canny-operator

I'm trying to detect lines from a noisy image and these are the steps I'm following:

```
img= cv2.imread('/content/spec_un45_3900000.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

[image]

```
img = 255 - cv2.medianBlur(img, 3) #Invert and blur
```

[image]

```
#Remove white spots from background
kernel = np.ones((1, 2), np.uint8)  
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel,iterations=2)
```

[image]

```
edges = cv2.Canny(opening,0,100,apertureSize = 3)
cv2_imshow(edges)
```

[image]

```
#Hough Line detection
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,
                        rho=1,
                        theta=np.pi/180,
                        threshold=100,
                        lines=np.array([]),
                        minLineLength=5,
                        maxLineGap=200)
for i in range(lines.shape[0]):
                cv2.line(out,
             (lines[i][0][0],
              lines[i][0][1]),
             (lines[i][0][2],
              lines[i][0][3]),
             (0,255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image]

I tried the method mentioned in [How to detect lines in noisy line images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593038/how-to-detect-lines-in-noisy-line-images)

Could someone help me debug this/provide a solution?

Comment: Please say what is wrong with your current solution, and also provide an additional, marked-up image showing the solution you wanted to get.

Comment: Why using `Canny`? And how you decided the threshold value for `HoughLinesP`?

Comment: @Emm the `opening` seems to be ok to detect the lines if they are horizontal, just sum the rows, and find the rows with mak sum values (maybe you need to set a threshold)

Comment: Try multiple passes of median filtering. Also if needed multiple passes of your morphology.

Comment: do you care about how long it takes the program to run?

Comment: how straight are those lines? mathematically straight or "close enough"? how were these pictures made?

Comment: are those lines always horizontal?

Comment: The lines are horizontal lines

Comment: In that case, it is probably sufficient to just sum the pixels across the rows using `np.sum(image, axis=1)` and look for rows with low sums (or low means).

Comment: @MarkSetchell Without any other operations?

Comment: yes, try it, then plot the profile curve. you'll see the extrema nicely. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxB5o.png

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Feel free to make an answer with your helpful plot.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The problem with this is that I don't know how i can set a threshold automatically. I also want to find the coordinates of the detected lines

Comment: you may not know how to set the thresholds but I *can't* know because your single image doesn't give me any idea of the possible variation. show us the faintest line you expect to still detect.

Comment: I just remembered I already answered such a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293813/whats-the-best-way-to-find-lines-on-a-very-poor-quality-image-knowing-the-angl/65296375#65296375 that one's lines are a lot fainter. and there's automatic threshold selection.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very efficient answer, but it's robust against heavy noise and the kernel filtering idea is useful for single-scale matching (it doesn't handle changes in scale) tasks.

With Original Image (ksize = 201, thresh = 150)

[image]

With Last Image (ksize = 51, thresh = 200)

[image]

The basic idea is to create a kernel that matches the image/shape you want. Then you can convolve it over the image and look for hotspots. At the end I skeletonize the mask to get rid of thick lines (running hough-lines over the mask hopefully only gets a single line back instead of a bunch).

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

# rescale image
def scale(img, scale_factor):
    h,w = img.shape[:2];
    h = int(h*scale_factor);
    w = int(w*scale_factor);
    return cv2.resize(img, (w,h));

# chops padding
def unpad(img, padsize):
    h,w = img.shape[:2];
    img = img[padsize:h-padsize, padsize:w-padsize];
    return img;

# WARNING: be aware of the direction of the zero (positive vs negative)
def zero_catch(value):
    zeroish = 0.00001
    if value <= zeroish:
        return zeroish
    return value

# get line endpoints
def get_coords(x, y, angle, imwidth, imheight):
    x1_length = (x-imwidth) / zero_catch(math.cos(math.radians(angle)));
    y1_length = (y-imheight) / zero_catch(math.sin(math.radians(angle)));
    length = max(abs(x1_length), abs(y1_length));
    endx1 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle));
    endy1 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle));

    x2_length = (x-imwidth) / zero_catch(math.cos(math.radians(angle+180)));
    y2_length = (y-imheight) / zero_catch(math.sin(math.radians(angle+180)));
    length = max(abs(x2_length), abs(y2_length));
    endx2 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle+180));
    endy2 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle+180));

    return int(endx1), int(endy1), int(endx2), int(endy2);

# skinny up the image
def skeletonize(img):
    size = np.size(img)
    skel = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
    done = False

    while( not done):
        eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
        temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
        temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
        skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
        img = eroded;

        zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
        if zeros==size:
            done = True
    return skel;

# load image
filepath = "noisy_lines.png";
img = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
orig_height, orig_width = img.shape[:2];

# pad to avoid edge dropoff
pad = int(orig_width/2);
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT, None)

# get mask
_, mask = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU);
height,width = mask.shape;

# background canvas
canvas = np.zeros_like(mask);

# super brute force solution
ksize = 51; # tweakable scale setting
center = int(ksize / 2);
kernel = np.zeros((ksize, ksize), np.uint8);

# draw line
start_angle = -60;
angle = start_angle; # start offset so that we can see the 0 degree get drawn
while angle < start_angle + 180:
    kernel = np.zeros((ksize,ksize), np.float32);
    sx, sy, ex, ey = get_coords(center, center, angle, ksize, ksize);
    kernel = cv2.line(kernel, (sx,sy), (ex,ey), 1.0 / ksize, 1);
    angle += 1;

    # convolve
    conv = cv2.filter2D(mask, -1, kernel, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT);

    # paint onto canvas
    _, linemask = cv2.threshold(conv, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY); # tweakable sensitivity setting
    canvas = cv2.bitwise_or(canvas, linemask);

    # chop off padding
    display_canvas = unpad(canvas, pad);
    display_conv = unpad(conv, pad);

    # stack the images
    sbs = np.hstack((display_canvas, display_conv));
    sbs = scale(sbs, 0.5);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("side-by-side", sbs);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);
    if key == ord('q'):
        break;

# show image
cv2.destroyAllWindows();
display_canvas = unpad(canvas, pad);
display_canvas = skeletonize(display_canvas);
orig_img = cv2.imread(filepath);
cv2.imshow("Image", orig_img);
cv2.imshow("Canvas", display_canvas);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: As a note, I think this is pretty much what houghlines is supposed to do. There's probably some amount of parameter tweaking that will get you the lines even without this kind of filtering. It's just that houghlines has a bunch of parameters that I've never properly learned (and I want to show this solution since it's useful for noisy template matching tasks in general).

Comment: this looks like a radon transform. no need for the kernels. just rotate to various angles and sum up scanlines.

Comment: Since this result looks like very same as OP's, I can't understand what is improved/answered.

Comment: woops, my bad. I didn't read the question carefully, I thought the last image was the challenge image. I'll swap in the original at the top.

Comment: @Christoph yep, since we're using a straight line kernel this has a similar flavor. I still like this method for finding multiple lines with different lengths and angles. It can also be used for finding patterns that aren't straight lines. There are plenty of answers for detecting straight lines so I wanted to add an answer that did something more generalized.